# How to get information about layers using Arcpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy

I have this layer structure in ArcMap:

[image]

"Localities, Gazeteers, Bases, Regions, and Territorial Claims are all Group Layers. All others under these are layers. I have a script that uses the Arcpy `Describe` method to go under each layer and get its full directory path. Here is the script:

```
import arcpy
mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
dataframes=arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)
for dataframe in dataframes:
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", dataframe):
        if not lyr.isGroupLayer:    
            print(arcpy.Describe(lyr).catalogPath)
```

This would return something like: `C:/Folder/Subfolder/layer.shp`
Now, I am trying to figure out a way to get the path of each layer relative to the map. For example, for layer `"features_multipoint"`, I need the script to report something like this:

```
MapDocument/Localities/Gazeteers/features_multipoint
```

The [Describe](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000013000000) method seems to not provide such capabilities.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [`lyr.longName`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000008000000)

> longName
>   (Read Only)
>
> This property is valuable when trying to determine whether a layer belongs to a group layer. If a layer does not belong to a group layer, the long name will equal the layer name. If a layer does belong to a group layer, the group layer structure will be included in the long name. For example, the name of a layer nested inside a group layer within another group layer may look something like Group1\Group2\LayerName. All layer types support this property.